# Image is not scaled to full screen

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-image

I am trying to decode the image before drawing it in Canvas. The procedure I followed is same as mentioned in http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

### Issue :

The image is scaled only to 70% of the screen. Can you please let me know if I miss any parameters ?

```
    public  Bitmap getAssetImage(Context context, String filename) throws IOException {

         //Decode image size
         final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         options.inJustDecodeBounds = true; 
         BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.backgroundhomepage, options); 
         //The new size we want to scale to
         final int REQUIRED_WIDTH= (int) dWidth;
         final int REQUIRED_HIGHT= (int) dHeight;
         //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
         int inSampleSize=1;
            if (options.outHeight > REQUIRED_HIGHT || options.outWidth > REQUIRED_WIDTH) {

                // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
                final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) options.outHeight / (float) REQUIRED_HIGHT);
                final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) options.outWidth / (float) REQUIRED_WIDTH);

                // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
                // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
                // requested height and width. 
                inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio; 
            }
            /*
         while(options.outWidth/inSampleSize/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && options.outHeight/inSampleSize/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
             inSampleSize*=2; */
         //Decode with inSampleSize
         BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         o2.inSampleSize=inSampleSize;    
         o2.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
         return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),R.drawable.backgroundhomepage, o2);
    }  




    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      Log.i("Notice", "In run of mybringback"); 
        if(backgoundImage == null){ 
            try {Log.i("MyBringBack", "In run of mybringback.. getting the image of background"); 
                backgoundImage = getAssetImage(getApplicationContext(),"backgroundhomepage");  
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ourHolder = getHolder();
        while (isRunning) {
//          Log.i("DragDrop", "ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()" +  ourHolder.getSurface().isValid() );
            if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            } 
            canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();    
            screenCenterX = dWidth / 2;
            screenCenterY = dHeight / 2; 
            canvas.drawBitmap(backgoundImage, 0, 0, null);   
            if (imagePublishDone) {
                if(!welcomeDone){ 
                    message = "Drop your wish to panda";
                    tts.speak(message, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    welcomeDone=true;
                }
                moveImageInEllipticalPath();
            } else {
                initialImagePublish();
            }

            centreReached = false;
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like it might be a density issue. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html

Comment: how this can be solved ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the problem yet. In which density folder did you put your image? What are the dimensions of that image? On what device are you currently testing?

Comment: Device - Sony xperia mini  (height - 320 and width - 480) and the image size is (height - 787 and width - 1280)

Answer (score 0):

```
     final int REQUIRED_WIDTH= Screen_width;
     final int REQUIRED_HIGHT= screen_height;
```

Calculate screen dimensions first

```
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
 Point size = new Point();
 display.getSize(size);
 int screen_width = size.x;
 int screen_height = size.y;
```